# How I fit long formula well within margin?

Tags: amsart

How I can fit the long formula (2.1) within margin? Since the formula is a fraction so use of two lines can not serve my purpose.
Please see code below:

**Edit: @Bernard has suggested \splitfrac which works with mathtool package, but when we use breqn package with it a label '1' is introduced in split fraction.**

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% (CMDE) Computational Methods for Differential Equations, University of Tabriz, Tabriz, Iran.
%
%LaTeX Paper ************************************************
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[fleqn,reqno,11pt]{amsart}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[pdftex,marginratio=1:1,width=130mm,height=190mm,top=40mm,headsep=17mm,head=7mm,footskip=11.29mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta,anchorcolor=blue,bookmarksopen,pdfpagetransition={Wipe}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% THEOREMS -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
% MATH ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}


% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\unitlength 1cm\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(2,1){ \scriptsize
\textbf{(CMDE)} \textsl{Computational Methods for Differential
Equations}}\end{picture}

\title[Please insert short title(at most 10 word)]{Please insert title}%
\author[F. Author]{First Author}%
\address{address 1}%
\email{email 1}%

\author[S. Author]{Second Author$^*$}%
\address{address 2}%
\email{email 2}%
\thanks{$*$ corresponding}

\author[T.  Author]{Third  Author}%
\address{address 2}%
\email{email 2}%


\subjclass[2010]{65L05, 34K06, 34K28.}
\keywords{Keyword1, keyword2, keyword3.}

%\date{}%
%\dedicatory{}%
%\commby{}%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{abstract}
Abstract is required and should summarize, in less
than 300 words, the context, content and conclusions of the
paper. It should not contain any references or displayed
equations.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
Contributions must be in English. Authors are encouraged to have
their contribution checked for grammar. Abbreviations are allowed but
should be spelt out in full when first used.  Integers ten and below
are to be spelt out but type as (2+1) dimensions.  Italicize foreign
language phrases (e.g.~Latin, French).

\section{Equations}
Displayed equations should be numbered consecutively in each
section, with the number set flush right and enclosed in
parentheses.
\begin{align}
 \label{56}A_{12}=\frac{\alpha_{1}^{3}\beta_{2}+3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{1}-3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}-3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{1}+3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{2}+\alpha_{2}^{3}\beta_{1}-6\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+2\beta_{1}\gamma_{2}+2\beta_{2}\gamma_{1}}{\alpha_{1}^{3}\beta_{2}+3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{1}+3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}+3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{1}+3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{2}+\alpha_{2}^{3}\beta_{1}-6\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+2\beta_{1}\gamma_{2}+2\beta_{2}\gamma_{1}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't think you should try to fit all of that within the margin.

Comment: Is it possible to compress font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\splitfrac`  command, from `mathtools`

```
    \documentclass[fleqn,reqno,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[pdftex,marginratio=1:1,width=130mm,height=190mm,top=40mm,headsep=17mm,head=7mm,footskip=11.29mm]{geometry}
        \usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta,anchorcolor=blue,bookmarksopen,pdfpagetransition={Wipe}]{hyperref}
        \usepackage{graphicx}

        \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
        \newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
        \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
        \newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proposition}
        \theoremstyle{definition}
        \newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
        \newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
        \numberwithin{equation}{section}

        \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
        \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
        \newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
        \usepackage{mathtools}

        \begin{document}
        \unitlength 1cm\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(2,1){ \scriptsize
        \textbf{(CMDE)} \textsl{Computational Methods for Differential
        Equations}}\end{picture}

        \title[Please insert short title(at most 10 word)]{Please insert title}%
        \author[F. Author]{First Author}%
        \address{address 1}%
        \email{email 1}%

        \author[S. Author]{Second Author$^*$}%
        \address{address 2}%
        \email{email 2}%
        \thanks{$*$ corresponding}

        \author[T. Author]{Third Author}%
        \address{address 2}%
        \email{email 2}%


        \subjclass[2010]{65L05, 34K06, 34K28.}
        \keywords{Keyword1, keyword2, keyword3.}

        %\date{}%
        %\dedicatory{}%
        %\commby{}%
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{abstract}
        Abstract is required and should summarize, in less
        than 300 words, the context, content and conclusions of the
        paper. It should not contain any references or displayed
        equations.
        \end{abstract}
        \maketitle
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------
        \section{Introduction}
        Contributions must be in English. Authors are encouraged to have
        their contribution checked for grammar. Abbreviations are allowed but
        should be spelt out in full when first used. Integers ten and below
        are to be spelt out but type as (2+1) dimensions. Italicize foreign
        language phrases (e.g.~Latin, French).

        \section{Equations}
        Displayed equations should be numbered consecutively in each
        section, with the number set flush right and enclosed in
        parentheses.

        \begin{align}
        \label{56}A_{12}=\frac{\splitfrac{\alpha_{1}^{3}\beta_{2}+3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{1}-3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}
        -3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{1}+3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{2}}{+\alpha_{2}^{3}\beta_{1}-6\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+2\beta_{1}\gamma_{2}
        +2\beta_{2}\gamma_{1}}}%
        {\splitfrac{\alpha_{1}^{3}\beta_{2}+3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{1}+3\alpha_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}+3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{1}
        +3\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}^{2}\beta_{2}}{+\alpha_{2}^{3}\beta_{1}-6\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+2\beta_{1}\gamma_{2}+2\beta_{2}\gamma_{1}}}
        \end{align}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also use package "{breqn}" for auto breaking of other equations but using this package produce label '1' in split fraction .

Comment: since this is just a single line, it is recommended to use `equation` rather than `align`.